# How can I use Microsoft Graph with OpenIdConnect and Identity in my .Net Core web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect, identity

We have a web app with several modules and I am trying to integrate Microsoft Graph. I started with one of the example projects I found online, which worked just fine. I was able to connect to my sharepoint site and read the files I needed to read. So far so good. In that example code, I don't see anywhere where it gets a token or anything like that. I sign in and approve the permissions request, and I'm off and running.

Now, I am trying to integrate that into my web application. We use OpenIdConnect, which the sample used. But we also use Identity. In our account controller, we have an ExternalLoginCallback function. The startup file code is below, and then below that is the meat of the Account Controller call.

When I try to do a simple thing, like get my information on SharePoint (currentUser = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().WithAuthenticationScheme("OpenIdConnect").GetAsync();) and I get the following error:

IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent.

No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

Startup code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string[] initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "URCS.Session";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            

            services.AddDbContext<UnitRateContractSystemContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();


            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options => { 
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:OAuth"];
                    options.MetadataAddress = options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Meta"];
                });

            services.AddResponseCompression();

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UnitRateContractSystemContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddUserStore<UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, UnitRateContractSystemContext, Guid, ApplicationUserClaim<Guid>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>>()
                .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<ApplicationRole, UnitRateContractSystemContext, Guid, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>>();


            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();


            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages();

            //Add mvc and json services
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
            {
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
            });

        }
```

Account Controller ExternalCallBack method (abbreviated)

```
    var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);

    if (info == null)
    {
        _accountProvider.LogInformation(new LoginLog
        {
            Message = $"Failed in getting GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()",
            MethodName = "ExternalLoginCallback",
            MethodType = "GET",
            ReturnURL = returnUrl,
            Success = false,
        });
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
    }

    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: true, bypassTwoFactor: true);
```

I'm clearly missing a token or something else it needs, but I have no idea what I need to do. I've been pulling my hair out. I have another developer helping me, and he is just as frustrated. Nothing seems to work. Please help!

Comment: Have you checked that your app registrations in Azure contain the proper configuration to bypass user consent? Without that config set up properly, calling an endpoint from the back-end on behalf of the "user" or another app registration will require explicit consent to do things like access APIs, etc.

Comment: I looked in my app registration and I don't see anywhere that it says I can bypass user consent. I even looked in the manifest. We've had this registration for years, so maybe I need to create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this is that there is no answer. I was not able to get this to work correctly, and nobody else seems to be able to. So, what we did was start a brand new application for this one module. The new application uses all the standard stuff that comes with creating the app.

**Edit:** One more piece to this. I wanted to be able to secure my app with roles, etc... And I couldn't combine the old and new ways of doing things. I did figure out how to do this with Azure AD though (the new way). After you create roles in your registration, you can then use an attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "IAModule")]
```

Looks familiar, right? When you define your role in your registration, you need to set the "value" to what you want to use in this attribute. Strange, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you had `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>` which is asp.net core identity. You also had `services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp` which is using `Microsoft identity platform` and [they are different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

> ASP.NET Core Identity isn't related to the Microsoft identity platform

So even if they can work in your code, I think you also need to solve an issue which is: using Graph SDK to call graph API required an microsoft account sign in and got authorized first. But in your application, you had 2 kinds of authentication, when the users use their account stored in your application's database, they are not able to get authorized by Azure AD to call graph api then.

My workaround about your scenario is, using Azure AD client credential flow which doesn't require to let user sign in to get authorization to call graph API. If your requirement needs to let user query their own sharepoint site, then you need to get current signed-in user's profile in addition. By the way, you need to give application api permission instead of the delegated api permission.

Code snippet for client credential flow:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes)
var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't use the application api permissions, as it would give users way too much access on our SharePoint site. I'm using the line of getting the details for the user as a test, so to speak. I know that if I can do that, I can do the other things I need to do. I hear what you are saying about the two different Identity issue, it make sense. If I take out the .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration) line from the  first one, the MicrosoftGraph line doesn't work. And if I take out the other Identity call, other things don't work. I will play with it though.

Comment: thank your for your kind reply, I do have much test yesterday and found it looks hard/impossible to implement it then my post my workaround. I also know application permission would give users too much access on the site, so it's only suitable for users don't have access to the code. then we can define custom API for access restriction. anyway, this is just a workaround at most.